# Web form to Salesforce

Tags: form, field-mapping

So I have a Web Form, where the user Enters a **Unique number** which is already exists in a Custom Object along with few other fields in the form.

On hitting submit this creates a new Lead in Salesforce along with the **unique number field** mapped to Salesforce field on Leads.

Now my requirement is I need to map this Lead to the Custom Object record to which that **Unique number field** matches to. How can I achieve this ? Anything I can do while creating Web form ? or upon creation of lead can I track for the custom object record ID using this **unique number field** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing a trigger on lead creation(Preferably before create) and pick the associated record with the unique number and associate it with Lead.